# How to simply remove a group of entities from specific context with Magical Record?

Tags: swift, core-data, magicalrecord

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "users.@count == 0")

if let locations = PBOLocation.MR_findAllWithPredicate(predicate, inContext: context) as? [PBOLocation] {
    for location in locations {
        //what now?                        
    }
}
```

I need to remove every founded location from specific context.

`MR_deleteEntity`, `MR_deleteEntityInContext:` methods don't work

Answer (score 0):

For specific `context`:

```
for location in locations {
    context.deleteObject(location)
}
```